# open and read binary file (javascript)

Tags: javascript

I have a binary file on a server and I want to read it.

I did something like that to get the file :

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", file);
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        doSomething(request.responseText);
    }
}
request.send();
```

but after that I'm not really sure what to do... What is the proper way to do this ?

is there a way to use `fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer()` to do what I want to do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the responseType to arrayBuffer like so:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", file);
request.responseType = 'arrayBuffer'; // the important part
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (request.readyState == 4) {
      doSomething(request.mozResponseArrayBuffer || request.response); // your arrayBuffer
  }
}

request.send();
```

Comment: nice and simple, perfect !

Comment: `'arraybuffer'` needs to be all lowercase apparently